# Correlating Series.corr(series2) gives NAN why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two frames, and I use iloc to extract some values. After having two extractions I want to correlate them but the series.corr( series) returns NAN all the time. Any help would be appreciate ?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2.0], [3, 4], [5, 1], [7, 8],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2]], columns=["A", "B"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2], [3, 4.0], [5, 6.0], [7, 8],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2],[1, 2]], columns=["A", "B"])

df1_selection=df1.iloc[1:3, 1]
df1_numeric=pd.to_numeric(df1_selection, downcast='float')

df1_anotherselection=df1.iloc[5:7 , 1]

df1_2numeric=pd.to_numeric(df1_anotherselection, downcast='float')

df1_2numeric.reset_index(drop=True)
df1_numeric.reset_index(drop=True) 

#When I do this I get nan 
df1_numeric.corr(df1_2numeric)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

`df1_new=df1.iloc[1:3, 1]`

The iloc returned me a series but with a name in this case "B".

Therefore I had to either use 
`series.columname.corr(series2.columname)`

or I could just drop the column name.
In case you dont know the column name use:
`df.columns = [''] * len(df1_reseted.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

This one gives you a (2x2) matrix, you can try this one.

```
df1_2numeric = df1_2numeric.reset_index(drop=True)
df1_numeric = df1_numeric.reset_index(drop=True)

new = pd.concat([df1_2numeric,df1_numeric], axis=1)
new.corr()
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me this    B   B
                                       B  1.0 NaN
                                     B  NaN NaN